# How can I fix the 'CORS policy' error I'm getting while trying to run my React-admin app on Rails 6 and ActiveStorage?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, react-admin

Im making use of Rails 6 and ActiveStorage to store files on S3.

I get a CORS error when I try to run my react-admin app.

Error message from my react-admin front end:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://my-backend.com' from origin 'http://my-react-admin-app.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
fetch.js:50     GET https://my-backend.com/data?_end=100&_order=ASC&_sort=id&_start=0&locale=en net::ERR_FAILED.
```

I have set up CORS policy for my bucket as follows (and it still wont work):

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "HEAD",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "X-Total-Count"
        ]
    }
]
```

Any pointers? - NOTE: everything works as it should when I run everything locally.

My gemfile has:

```
gem "rails", "~> 6.0.0"
gem "aws-sdk-s3", require: false
gem "rack-cors", "~> 1.0.3"
```

My cors.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins "*"
    resource "*",
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :delete, :options],
      expose: "X-Total-Count"
  end
end
```

Comment: I think your expose headers are not correct 

These are the list of expose headers which are allowed https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html

Comment: Believe you need to add OPTIONS to allowed methods

Comment: @dbugger S3 says the OPTIONS method is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see the error is due to CORS settings on the server (Rails backend) not with S3. This can be because 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is not present in the request resource that should be provided by Rails backend.

There are multiple steps you have to follow to solve this issue. Make sure to restart Rails server after making each of the following changes.

1. Ensure that CORS settings are correct in Rails server configuration (`config/application.rb` file or `config/initializers/cors.rb`). Your `cors.rb` looks fine but check whether it is located in `config/initializers` path and Rails application is picking it up correctly.

---

*If error still persist, then:*

2. Try adding the following settings to `config/application.rb` as follows: (Note: Replace `http://react-app.com` with actual frontend domain name.)

   module YourAppName
   class Application < Rails::Application
   # To initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version
   config.load_defaults 6.0

   ```
    # Rest of the code

    # To configure CORS
    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins 'http://react-app.com'
        resource '*',
          headers: :any,
          methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head],
          expose: ['X-Total-Count']
      end
    end
   ```

   end
   end

---

*If error still persist, then:*

3. Check for any proxies or any other server settings that can override your CORS settings. Check whether web server like Nginx or Apache is not stripping out CORS headers.

---

*If error still persist, then:*

4. Make sure domain of React App is listed in the `config.hosts` list in Rails configuration (especially if you are using Rails 6).

---

*If error still persist, then:*

5. If you are serving your aPI under a different path, then add the path to the `resources` statement as `resource 'api/*`

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Hi there. I tried every single one of these and nothing seems to work. Question, how excatly do I check if the cors.rb file is being picked up correctly? (it is in my intializers folder).

I attempted to add the header directly via nginx config following this article: https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/enable-cors-nginx/, but that didnt work either.